# How to show and hide a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I tried to  show and hide a button in `<fieldset>` by a javascript function.But it is not working.I did not find my mistake.

My FieldSet :

```
<fieldset class="buttons">
  <dx:ASPxButton ID="btn11" runat="server" Text="Buton 1">
  </dx:ASPxButton>
</fieldset>
```

My checkbox :

```
<input class="checkbox" id="ShowHideButton" name="ShowHideButton" type="checkbox" onchange="valueChanged()" />
<label for="ShowHideButton">ShowHideButton</label>
```

And my JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function valueChanged() {
    if ($('#ShowHideButton').is(":checked"))
      $(".buttons").show();
    else
      $(".buttons").hide();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you inspect the page and see what is the state of fieldset  and what is the state of dx:ASPxButton ?

Comment: See for any errors in console. ctrl+shift+j in google chrome.

Comment: @Mehmet Akyel can you give [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 3):

On the client side the actual id of the button won't be `ShowHideButton` ASP will generate a unique one for it.

You need to access it via `clientid` in your javascript.

Try this:

```
function valueChanged()
{
    if ($('#<%=ShowHideButton.ClientID%>').is(":checked"))
        $(".buttons").show();
    else
        $(".buttons").hide();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use

http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/7ZNzF/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//set initial state.
$('#ShowHideButton').val($(this).is(':checked'));

$('#ShowHideButton').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
        $(this).attr("checked", returnVal);
    }else{
        alert("sd");
    }
    $('#ShowHideButton').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys.I solved.I am a stupid I forgot add this library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why are you putting this here? It's a comment and should be in the comments area. Please familiarise yourself with SO.